# The type parameter E is hiding the type E. Generics template to a class

Tags: java, generics

I am practicing generics and i did the following.

Created a class called man as below.

```java
public class Man{
    int hands=2;
    int legs=2;
    boolean alive;
    
    public Man(boolean b) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        alive=b;
    }
}
```

created a class called person

```java
public class Person<Man> {
    Man p;
    String name;
    

    public Person(Man p, String name) {
        this.p = p;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Person() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

}
```

tried to instantiate a person of type string or int as below and it doesn't throw an error.

```
Person<String> p1 = new Person<String>(new String("test"), "test1");
    Person<Integer> p2=new Person<>(1,"test");
```

when i checked carefully, i got the following warning. "The type parameter Man is hiding the type Man"

So i understand that giving Man as a type parameter to the class Person is as good as giving 'E' in java examples. Its not Man.class. Why did this happen?
How do i assign my Man.class as the generic type parameter?

and can you throw me some good questions/practice exercises to learn generics.

Comment: Because `Man` is the name of a class in the same package. Just change the name of your generic from `Person<Man>` to `Person<T>` or something else that doesn't resemble nor `Man` nor any other class.

Comment: I don't get it. If you want `Person` to refer to the actual `Man` class, and you don't want `Person<String>` and `Person<Integer>` to be allowed, then why are you even using generics? It seems like you just want a normal `Person` class, that refers normally to the normal `Man` class, with no parameterization whatsoever.

Comment: Person is neither a subclass nor super class of Man. if i have classes of type animal and plant, i want to restrict them being used as generic types for Person.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `Man` is the name of a class in the same package. Just change the name of your generic from `Person<Man>` to `Person<T>` or something else that doesn't resemble nor `Man` nor any other class.

More about generics:

- [Java Tutorials. Lesson: Generics (Updated)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/)

---

Looks like you want that `Person` has only `Man` attribute using generics. You will need for that to have a super class that defines the generic and `Person` will inherit from it defining that it uses `Man` as the class used. Short example:

```
public abstract class AliveBeing<T> {
    protected T livingBeing;
    public AliveBeing(T livingBeing) {
        this.livingBeing = livingBeing;
    }
}

public class Person extends AliveBeing<Man> {
    //now your livingBeing field is from Man type...
    public Person(Man man) {
        super(man);
    }
}
```

This will make it but IMO this design is odd. It would be better to explain more about your current problem to get a better and accurate answer.

Note the difference:

```
//case 1
public class Foo<T> {
    //...
}

//case 2
public class Bar<E> extends Foo<E> {
    //...
}

//case 3
public class Baz extends Foo<String> {
    //...
}
```

In first case, `Foo` uses a generic class and you can refer to this class by `T`. In second case, `Bar` extends from `Foo` and declares using its own generic class and you can refer to it by `E`, but this `E` will be the same generic used from `Foo` (instead of `T` it will be `E`). In third case, `Baz` class extends from `Foo` but it won't define any generic behavior, instead it declares that the generic class used from `Foo` is `String`.

Comment: Person is neither a subclass nor super class of Man. if i have classes of type animal and plant, i want to restrict them being used as generic types for Person

Comment: I never said `Man` was super class or subclass of `Person` nor viceversa. Please re read the answer.

Comment: So how can i restrict Plant or animal classes from being used as type parameters?

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped. But im still trying to figure out why the generic type man cannot be directly applied to AliveBeing or Person? Is there a specific reason generics are designed this way? I am just learning generics. i didnt have a problem to work on.

Comment: Answer updated one more time. Please let me know if there's something else you still don't get.

Comment: Thank you. Awesome explanation. freed my mind :) Can i email you if i have questions?

Comment: It will be better if you post your questions here, maybe I won't have time to answer all your emails :(.