# Type parameter wasn't resolved correctly

Tags: java, generics

I had two public static subclasses in my main class:

```
public class Main {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
     ...
   }

   public static class Obj {
     public void foo() {
     }
     ...
   }

   public static class ObjList<Obj> {
     private ArrayList<Obj> objList;
     
     public void bar() {
       for(Obj obj: objList)
         obj.foo();     // Error here, cannot resolve method foo()
     
   }
```

In this case, i cannot access Obj's instance method foo() inside ObjList class. And if i hover over type parameter Obj, it shows "type parameter Obj extends Object"

If i change ObjList like this:

```
public static class ObjList<T extends Obj> {
}
```

then the error is gone, and when i hover over Obj, it correctly shows "public static class Main.Obj extends Object"

I wonder why the previous declaration didn't work.

Comment: `ObjList` does not need the generic parameter. In its current form, `<Obj>` is interpreted as a (variable) type (like `T` in the second example) and those are by default bounded by `Object`. Remove it and the code works as expected.

Comment: You are using generics where it is not needed!!

Comment: Get rid of the type variable hiding the name `Obj`: `public static class ObjList {`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19761890/the-type-parameter-e-is-hiding-the-type-e-generics-template-to-a-class https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10178377/java-generics-the-type-parameter-string-is-hiding-the-type-string

Comment: Thank you all, i realize i made a very silly mistake.